# Conditional css class assign in angular 2

Tags: angularjs, angular

I have a grid with checkbox, I am putting checked values in an array (currentFocusedRow), now I want to assign **activeRow** class to the checked row:

```
// app.ts
class contact {
  public contactlist = [{icontact_id: "contact1"}, {icontact_id: "contact2"}, {icontact_id: "contact3"}, {...}];
  public currentFocusedRow = ["contact2", "contact3"];
}

// app.html
<tr *ngFor="let contact of contactlist"
   [class.activeRow]="contact.icontact_id == currentFocusedRow">
   ...
</tr>
```

now since currentFocusedRow is an array i can't simply check like that (contact.icontact_id == currentFocusedRow) there should be something to check if the value is present in that array or not like **indexOf**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checking with indexOf in directive itself worked, this is pretty amazing that we can use this JS methods directly in DOM:

```
<tr *ngFor="let contact of contactlist;"
    [class.activeRow]="currentFocusedRow.indexOf(contact.icontact_id) != '-1'">
</tr>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this should work for you:

Typescript

```
isActive(id) {
    return this.currentFocusedRow.indexOf(id) !== -1
}
```

HTML

```
<tr *ngFor="let contact of contactlist"
    [class.activeRow]="isActive(contact.icontact_id)">
</tr>
```

Comment: Yeah I can do that as well but checking directly in DOM seems to be more convenient.

Comment: You can simply paste the code in to the [class.activeRow] block

Comment: like this: [class.activeRow]="currentFocusedRow.indexOf(contact.icontact_id) !== -1"

Comment: However i don't think there is any change in performance. It's simply a matter of how you want to format your code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use index of the object that is current object, by using:

```
<tr *ngFor="let contact of contactlist; let i = index">
```

Which will enable you to get those indexes.

Apart from that, you can just use [NgClass](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgClass-directive.html) directive.

Comment: how indexes will help me here? Are you suggesting to put something like this ```[class.activeRow]="contact.icontact_id == currentFocusedRow[i]"``` it won't work